# connecting html buttons to smart contract

Tags: html, frontend, smartcontracts

I'm trying to build a faucet for my token out of pure HTML. I know using react, nextjs, moralis etc would be better, but i want this to be purely done on a html.

This is my smart contract function

```
function requestATN(address to) external {
        if(block.timestamp - lastReceived[msg.sender] < 24 hours){
            revert ATN20__DailyLimitReached();
        }
        lastReceived[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        _mint(to, requestAmount);

        emit ATNSent(to, requestAmount);
    }
```

i already connected the front end to my metamask, what i want is to get the button responsible for calling this function to be responsive. This is my current try;

```
    async function requestATN() {
       const requestATN = document.getElementsByClassName("button button1").requestATN()
       const requestATNPromise = AtlanteanNotesContract.requestATN();
       await requestATNPromise;
    }
```

This is my button;

```
<button class="button button1" onClick={requestATN}>Mint</button>
```

like you guessed, its not working. Can i get a little assistance?